# java Calendar get(calendar.MONTH) returns 0

Tags: java

Why does calendar.get(calendar.MONTH) return 0(zero)  here: ?

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse("2013-02-12");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTime(date);

System.out.println( calendar.get(calendar.MONTH) ); // 0 ??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MM` for month and `mm` minute. Use format - `yyyy-MM-dd`, you will get desired output which is `1`.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-02-12");
```

Comment: Yes..Thx. I start answering my own question, as soon as I posted one.

Comment: All I can tell you that is :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it.. Sorry..

The answer: because I use "mm" but not "MM"

Answer (score 2):

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")` should be `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`